# Draggable image within a vertical content

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to create the effect of an image draggable using boundaries. well, i have an image with a fixed width but a variable height. i have the next code:

```
<div class="image_holder">
   <div class="image_content"></div>
</div>
```

well, "image_holder" set the visible area of the image acting as a mask, with its width=180px, height=90px and overflow=hidden properties set.

when i load the image into "image_content", normally, the height is higher but masked and only visible the area of "image_holder".

The question is that when i use the jquery draggable function, its works fine but i need to set boundaries. i use the next code:

```
$("#draggable").draggable({axis: 'y', containment: [0, $('.image_holder').offset().top-excess, 180, $('.image_holder').offset().top+90+excess], cursor: "crosshair"});
```

'excess' is a calculation from:

```
var excess = $('#draggable').height() - 90;
```

My problem is that I'm not able to delimitate properly the containment area for dragging the image without the image leave the visible area.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly; you can achieve this by monitoring the drag event as follows:

```
$('img').draggable({
    axis: 'y',
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        var pos = ui.position;
        var $this = $(this);

        if((pos.top * -1) >= ($this.height() - $this.parent().height()))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(pos.top > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Basically if the image is about to go outside the bounds of the container just return `false`

[DRAG DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QLZzg/1/)